# How to join four tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have four tables in SSMS, I'm trying to write a script for a table variable that will hold the results of all four, basically, it will be like my table tshow which is in the picture.
This is what I have so far for the Table Variable so far:

[image]

```sql
DECLARE @mShowsTable Table( 
MaskedSinger NCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Costumes NCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Song NCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
DateSung DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @mShowsTable
```

Comment: You appear to have truncated your attempt when you posted it. What was the full `INSERT` statement? Why didn't it work?

Comment: [Edit] your question, don't put it in the comments.

Comment: As an aside, avoid using table variables `DECLARE @x TABLE` and use temporary tables instead e.g., `CREATE TABLE #x`. Table variables don't have statistics, and therefore SQL Server assumes a fixed number of rows (often 1) leading to poor performance. See https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/table-variables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have been required to use the Table Variable, so the solution as shown below. Otherwise, *I agree with the comment saying Temp Table is better in terms of performance.*

**Note: You need to replace the data types with what matches your requirements.**

```
DECLARE @mShowsTable TABLE (
    MaskedSinger VARCHAR(200)
    ,Costumes VARCHAR(200)
    ,Song VARCHAR(200)
    ,DateSung DATETIME
    );

INSERT INTO @mShowsTable
SELECT M.MaskedSinger
    ,C.Customes
    ,SO.Song
    ,D.DateSung
FROM tShow S
INNER JOIN tCustomes C ON S.CustomesID = C.CustomesID
INNER JOIN tMaskedSingers M ON S.MaskedSingerID = M.MaskedSingerID
INNER JOIN tSong SO ON S.SongID = SO.SongID
INNER JOIN tDateSung D ON S.DateSungID = D.DateSungID

SELECT *
FROM @mShowsTable
```

The full script I used is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE tCustomes (CustomesID INT, Customes varchar(200))
CREATE TABLE tMaskedSingers (MaskedSingerID INT, MaskedSinger varchar(200))
CREATE TABLE tSong (SongID INT, Song varchar(200))
CREATE TABLE tDateSung (DateSungID INT, DateSung DateTime)
CREATE TABLE tShow (MaskedSingerID INT, CustomesID INT, SongID INT, DateSungID INT, ShowID INT)

INSERT INTO tCustomes  VALUES (1, 'ABCD'), (2, 'XYZ')
INSERT INTO tMaskedSingers  VALUES (1, 'SINGER 1'), (2, 'SINGER 2'), (3, 'SINGER 3')
INSERT INTO tSong  VALUES (1, 'SONG 1'), (2, 'SONG 2'), (3, 'SONG 3')
INSERT INTO tDateSung  VALUES (1, '2020-10-28'), (2, '2020-10-29'), (3, '2020-10-29'), (4, '2020-10-30')
INSERT INTO tShow  VALUES (1, 1,1,1,1), (2, 1,2,2,2), (2, 2,2,2,3)

DECLARE @mShowsTable TABLE (
    MaskedSinger VARCHAR(200)
    ,Costumes VARCHAR(200)
    ,Song VARCHAR(200)
    ,DateSung DATETIME
    );

INSERT INTO @mShowsTable
SELECT M.MaskedSinger
    ,C.Customes
    ,SO.Song
    ,D.DateSung
FROM tShow S
INNER JOIN tCustomes C ON S.CustomesID = C.CustomesID
INNER JOIN tMaskedSingers M ON S.MaskedSingerID = M.MaskedSingerID
INNER JOIN tSong SO ON S.SongID = SO.SongID
INNER JOIN tDateSung D ON S.DateSungID = D.DateSungID

SELECT *
FROM @mShowsTable

DROP TABLE tCustomes
DROP TABLE tMaskedSingers
DROP TABLE tSong
DROP TABLE tDateSung
DROP TABLE tShow
```

Giving the results

[image]